# CharacterController - should I work with FixedUpdate or with Update?

Tags: unity, physics

I know that updates related to the physics engine should be made in FixedUpdate, but I am not sure about updates related to CharacterController: should they be done in Update or FixedUpdate? I tried both options and putting them in FixedUpdate appears smoother, but this may be due to other factors, so I would be happy to know what the recommended practice is.

Comment: Do other objects in your game use physics? Does your character controller interact with other objects using physics?

Comment: @Kevin my character climbs stairs, platforms and ramps that have physical (non-trigger) colliders.